# Need help with jQuery AJAX and transition effects

Tags: jquery, ajax, effects, transition

OK guys, my website is almost finished - http://www.visualise.ca/

But there is one thing that really bugs me. When I click on a thumbnail to open a post which loads within the same page using AJAX and then click on another thumbnail to load another post the transition is not smooth and the image takes a while to load and it's ugly. Is there a way I can improve that and make everything smooth using fadeIn/fadeOut ?

Here is what I tried with no luck (active now).

```
$(".ajaxed").live("click", function(event) {
        $.address.crawlable(true).value($(this).attr("rel"));
        $("#content").fadeTo(500,0);
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 205}, 300);
        var post_slug = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#board").load("ajax/",{slug:post_slug});
        $("#board").delay(1500).slideDown("slow");
        return false;
});
```

Many thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I end up using.

```
$(".navig a").live("click", function(event) {
    var post_slug = $(this)[0].pathname.substring(1);
    var board_h = $("#board").height();
    $.address.crawlable(true).value(post_slug).strict(true);
    $("#board-wrapper").css('height', board_h + 'px');
    $("#board").fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $("#board").stop().load("ajax/",{slug:post_slug}, function(){
            $("#board").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                var board_h2 = $("#board").height();
                $("#board-wrapper").css('height', board_h2 + 'px');
            });

        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Just to let people know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".ajaxed").live("click", function(event) {
        var post_slug = $(this).attr("rel");
        $.address.crawlable(true).value(post_slug );
        $("#content").fadeTo(500,0);
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 205}, 300);
        $("#board").stop().load("ajax/",{slug:post_slug}, function(){
            $(this).slideDown("slow")
        });

        return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't see much difference.

Comment: Yes, but the board will slidedown only on load success and if its already animating it will stop before loading.